# How to read/write a file that is more than 200MB

Tags: java, file-io

I have seen and read some guide about reading and writing file txt, but in my project there are some little problem,for example my file is more then 200MB(is a xml file); anyway I want to read my file, a part of code is this:

> node id="1653281475" lat="44.499773" lon="11.350111" version="1"
>
> timestamp="2012-02-29T20:15:15Z" changeset="10831749" uid="91650" user="Alberto58">

```
tag k="barrier" v="gate"/>
tag k="bicycle" v="yes"/>
tag k="foot" v="yes"/>
tag k="car" v="yes"/>
```

> node/
> Other node:
> node id="16532843433" etc..........

I want to search only the node id "1653281475" and modify only the tag k="foot" v="yes" into k="foot" v="no" that is contain in this node.

How I can do it?

---

It is the second days that I am trying to read and write my xml document(now I am using a little 654byte xml)employees.xml, I have follow so many guide but I don't understand how I have to do, for example I follow this guide:

http://www.journaldev.com/1198/java-sax-parser-example-tutorial-to-parse-xml-to-list-of-objects

So I create 3 java file that are located in a directory name sax: Employee.java, MyHandler.java,XMLParserSAX.java(in witch there is some errors, the code is the same of the page that I have link)

When I use the command(I am in Ubuntu 12.04) javac sax/* there is no problem
but when I use java sax.XMLParserSAX employees.xml there are so many problem; first of all in the code there is an error at **"import com.journaldev.xml.Employee;"**-->cannot find symbol.
And the other error are the same but in other place like **"MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();"**...

I think that the problem is that the the XMLPArserSAX don't recognizes the class Employee...
What I have to do? =(

Comment: I wouldn't modify such a big file in place. Consider reading it line-wise or using SAX and write the modifications simultaneously to a new file.

Comment: it sounds like you're using a 200MB flat file for not just data access but also mutation. I can strongly advise not doing that and instead storing your data in either a regular database (it's what we invented them for) or something like a sqlite file (still 1 file, highly structured, with dedicated access libraries), instead.

Answer (score 4):

Do not load the whole file in memory. SAX parsers are made for exactly this kind of usage. Use a SAX parser to read the file. As you read each tag keep writing it to the output file - until you see `node id="1653281475"`. When you see this node, modify it and write it to the output file. Then continue writing the nodes to output file till end. Output file will have the modified XML in it at the end of this process.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answers, I am a beginner in Java, I don't know what is "SAX" and how to use it.. In my program I prefer to not use another file but to use the same... If is not possibile I will follow the advice that you have wrote; Can you give me some guide about SAX and what I have to do in each case?( Both using same file or using another one)

Comment: I followed this guide and i got "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"...i don't understand why!

Comment: You not have the SAX parser JAR file in the classpath? Check.

Comment: I don't undestand... Today I modify my SAXLocalNameCount.java with a stupid code(a println) and now, If i write javac sax/* it compile with some warning and not error, but if I do java sax.SAXLocalNameCount example.osm there is an error"It is impossible to find and load the main class " sax.SAXLocalNameCount"... I don't understand why! Yesterday It works! =(

Comment: I have resolve, I add at the begging of CLASSPATH=.:

Comment: Hello, how can I merge SAX with DOM? Because SAX is only for reading an input file, and DOM can't work with a big file such mine... I am desperate...

Comment: @Zoifil SAX should be enough for your use case. Why do you want to merge SAX and DOM?

Answer (score 0):

To process large portion of data we have to use event-oriented solutions. Use SAX or StAX API and write an element/attribute to the output file right after it is read from the input file. This will give you much-much better performance in terms of memory allocation and time of processing.